# pattern removing in excel (include symbol and words)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel column with pattern like this:

```
_17 "17" [factor=17],
_26 "26" [factor=26],
_30 "30" [factor=30],
_32 "32" [factor=32],
```

I have read some posts regarding using substitute in excel, but am not sure how should I do it.

The output I want is to keep only the number as shown:

```
17
26
30
32
```

Any help would be greatly appericated.

Comment: See the duplicates. In your case: `=-LOOKUP(1,-MID(A1,2,ROW($1:$99)))` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like MID.

```
mid(col,2,2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FILTERXML()` which is more versatile.

```
=FILTERXML(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","<t><s>")," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[1]")
```

[image]

Comment: You could cut this down to a single `SUBSTITUTE()` maybe? Something like `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"""","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[2]")`

Comment: Yes. This works just fine.